# How to split multiple columns to few columns?

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following data:

```
 X  Y  Z    X  Y  Z   X  Y  Z   
 1  2  3    4  5  6   7  8  9

 X  Y  Z    X  Y  Z   X  Y  Z    
10 11 12   13 14 15  16 17 18
```

I want to re-arrange it like this:

```
 X  Y  Z        
 1  2  3    

 X  Y  Z       
 4  5  6   

 X  Y  Z       
 7  8  9  

 X  Y  Z       
10 11 12  

 X  Y  Z       
13 14 15

 X  Y  Z       
16  17 18
```

using `awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'`, I can print the set of columns but could not arrange in the desired fashion as described above.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: will you have only 4 rows as you shown in your sample input file or more?

Comment: No, I have 96 rows. each x , y and z corresponds to 1 set of values.

Comment: No there is no blank character,

Comment: Yes, exactly. In below answer section, @John1024 has almost solved the problem.
But I can not able to extend it.

Comment: No, I dont have any blank lines after each data line. Is this a just typing error. Actually, I am new to this platform, so couldnt type correctly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, Now, this is the correct format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
# numCols in how many fields are required in output, can be passed as -v numCols=<number>
BEGIN { OFS="\t"; numCols=(numCols ? numCols : 3) }
!NF { prt(); numRows=0; next }
{
    ++numRows
    numGrps = 0
    colNr = 0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        colNr = ( (i - 1) % numCols ) + 1
        numGrps += ( colNr == 1 ? 1 : 0 )
        val[numGrps,numRows,colNr] = $i
    }
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   rowNr, grpNr, colNr) {
    for (grpNr=1; grpNr<=numGrps; grpNr++) {
        for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
            for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
                printf "%s%s", val[grpNr,rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
X       Y       Z
1       2       3

X       Y       Z
4       5       6

X       Y       Z
7       8       9

X       Y       Z
10      11      12

X       Y       Z
13      14      15

X       Y       Z
16      17      18
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk '!(NR%2){for (i=1;i<=NF-2;i=i+3){print a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2]; print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}} {split($0,a)}' file
```

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
 X  Y  Z    X  Y  Z   X  Y  Z
 1  2  3    4  5  6   7  8  9
 X  Y  Z    X  Y  Z   X  Y  Z
10 11 12   13 14 15  16 17 18
```

Now run our command:

```
$ awk '!(NR%2){for (i=1;i<=NF-2;i=i+3){print a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2]; print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}} {split($0,a)}' file
X Y Z
1 2 3
X Y Z
4 5 6
X Y Z
7 8 9
X Y Z
10 11 12
X Y Z
13 14 15
X Y Z
16 17 18
```

#### How it works

- `!(NR%2){for (i=1;i<=NF-2;i=i+3){print a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2]; print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2)}}`

  On even numbered lines, print three values from the previous line (stored in array `a`), then three values from the current line and repeat until all values are printed.
- `split($0,a)`

  Save the values from the current line in array `a`.

Comment: Hi, John, Can extend this? Under each X Y Z, I have 11 values.

Comment: @AmanullahMalik  If you have 11 values, then you no longer have groups of three.  So, you are really asking a different question and an explanation would be needed for what your input and desired output is in that case.